# What does "Binkssssss, yousa havena liveplay with thisen hisen" mean?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

> Jinn: He owes me what you call a "life-debt."  Your gods demand that his life belongs to me now.
>
> Rugor Nass: Binkssssss, **yousa havena liveplay with thisen hisen**? Uh-huh. Begone wit him!

What does "Binkssssss, yousa havena liveplay with thisen hisen" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's translate it:

- yousa: *you* or *you are* or *did you*...?
- havena: the Gungan version of *to have*
- liveplay: anything that would involve your​ life at stake.
- with: literally the same word
- thisen: the Gungan version of *this*
- hisen: *human*

So its full translation:

> Did you have a life play (life debt) with this human?

[Source](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Gungan_Basic)

Comment: I'm not sure about 'hisen' as a translation of 'human', despite what wookieepedia says. Nass uses the word earlier to refer to Binks. **[BOSS NASS:** *Binkss brokeen the nocombackie law. **Hisen** to be pune-ished](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html).*

Comment: This page https://talklikejarjarday.com/gungan_language translate it to *his* but the Wookiepedia translation fits.

Comment: That website appears to be a fan creation - "*This site is not endorsed or affiliated with Lucasfilm Ltd.*"

Comment: Without any evidence to substantiate it, perhaps “his person” could be considered, doesn’t fit 100% as an english translation, but seems to fit adequately for meaning?

Comment: @bpilling Or more simply, "hisen" is a 3rd-person masculine singular pronoun.

Answer (score 1):

The accurate translation would be "You have a life-debt with this man/person?"

As can be derived from other dialogue in the script:

**Yousa - *You/your/you are***

- Yousa point is well seen - *Your point is well taken*.
- Yousa goen tada Bosses. - *You're going to the Bosses.*
- Yousa in big dudu this time. - *You're in deep shit this time.*
- Wesa wish no nutten in yousa tings... - *We wish no involvement in your affairs...*
- Wesa give yousa una bongo. - *We'll give you a bongo.*

**havena - *to have***

- No other examples in script

**liveplay - *life-debt***

- no other examples in script, but obvious from Nass translating Qui-gon's term "life debt" into this.

**with - *with***

- same word as in normal English (sorry, "Galactic Standard")

**thisen - *this***

- no other examples in script, but obvious in context

**hisen - *his/he is***

- Hisen to be pune-ished. - *He is to be punished.*
- Hisen live tis yos - *His life is yours.*

The problem is that "Begone wit him!" is used by Nass, so "hisem" can't necessarily be a straight replacement for "him". On the other hand, the entire phrase "thisen hisem" could indicate a definitive third person pronomial phrase in some contexts. There's also no way of telling if they have gender differentiation in this case.

Well, to be honest the main problem is that it's not like they had a linguist to keep things consistent.